# Make a .java file Portable

Tags: java

I am writing a source code library that is supposed to be included in various different projects.  Ideally I can just include my library with different projects, but what gets me is the 'package' statement in my library.

If I specify `package my_package`, I end up assuming some directory structure. But each project has different directory structures. That makes it impossible to incorporate it with different projects.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You get the downvotes probably because the question seems to displays three traits: a complete and utter lack of Java knowledge exposure (if you used a single library in your life, even as simple as Swing, you would know the answer); lack of even trying to find the answer (there are thousands of libraries and example projects available) and the air of doing something big and iportant. The real question is: how can you even start writing a reusable library without understanding basics of the language, its compilation and packaging?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how libraries are used in Java.

You normally do not copy the source code of a library into whatever project you want to use it on. The library is a separate project that is compiled into a JAR file, and in projects that you want to use this library you put the JAR file for the library on the classpath.

For the project that uses the library, it doesn't matter what package the library is in. As long as the JAR is on the classpath, you can import classes from the library.

There are many thousands of free and open source libraries for Java available, and almost any project uses multiple third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Your library's package structure would be irrelevant to an including project's structure. They just add your .jar to the classpath and then they can import my_package.Whatever into the consuming code.

Answer (score 0):

Your library will live in some package that you choose for your library.  Any project that uses your library will then import the class(es) from that package.  This is normal.  If the source is copied into each project (note that this can lead to project management issues), then they will simply place the directory as specified by the library, which is independent of the rest of the package structure of the project.